# send a big byte array through java socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a big byte array of length more than 1200000. I want to send it by DataOutputStream, and receive at client by DataInputStream.

I'm using the code

```
    out.write(outData)

    in.readFully(inData)
```

out is DataOutputStream, in is DataInputStream, outData is the byte array I want to send.
When I run the program, if the length of byte array is around 120000, the array can be sent, but when the length becomes 1200000, the server cant receive the array. Should I split the big array into some small ones?

I tried such code below, but it still not working.

```
        out.writeInt(outData.length);

        int start = 0;
        int len = 0;
        int count = outData.length;

        while (count > 0) {
            if (count < 4096) 
                len = count;
            else len = 4096;

            out.write(outData, start, len);
            start += len;
            count -= len;
        }
```

and

```
        int length=in.readInt();
        byte[] inData=new byte[length];
        in.readFully(inData);
```

Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: You can send as big as you want using `socket.write()` don't have to cache it yourself Java does that for you.. But receiving is a different story it will come in at random you have to have some kind of identifier to cut the packets yourself or else it will just be a long never ending packet.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to do that. Post the code, and elaborate on "the server cant receive the array". Tell us *precisely* what happens.

Comment: What protocol are you using? TCP or UDP?

Comment: You could frame the bytes with {SOH}[message bytes]{ETX}, and on the receive side read into a buffer starting at SOH -> ETX, stopping then to construct your objects from the recieved bytes.

Comment: I'm using TCP protocol, is it not ok i use in.readFully(inData) to cut the message at receiver?

Answer (score 1):

In writer:

`for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    dataoutputstream.writeByte(bytearray[i]);
}`

In reader:

`for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    bytearray[i]=datainputstream.readByte();
}`